# Gnuplot integer overflow

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file that I want to plot in gnuplot. Syntax goes as such ;

```
0 1556626208759228959
1 1556626208700312846
0 1556626208700456361
1 1556626208745168734
0 1556626208745256732
1 1556626208933206888
0 1556626208933304231
1 1556626209260757685
0 1556626209260865081
1 1556626209670994584
0 1556626209671087092
1 1556626209672478372
```

and when I gnuplot 'filename.dat' I get :

```
warning integer overflow changing to floating point
```

error and no plot is displayed. What would be the possible solution for this ?

Comment: What is your exact plot command? Which version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: I try  : gnuplot plot 'filename.dat'  and version is 5.2

Comment: strange, I have 5.2.6 and get a plot and no error message. Are there any other settings you did before? Maybe try `reset session` before.

Comment: The floating point error is not the error leading to no plot, I can get gnuplot 5.2 to plot the data you give. Give more detail

Comment: ah, I guess, you are not plotting from the gnuplot command line but from the console of your operating system. Try `gnuplot -p -e "plot 'filename.dat'"`

Comment: If plotting column 2 vs column 1 of this data, you'll only get a few tiny (blue) `+' symbols on the axes (0 or 1 abcissae) which you'll easily miss when looking at your plot. So I guess that's what happens, everything plots all right but you're not seeing what you expect. Zoom out e.g. or change your plot command.

Answer (score 0):

In version v5.4 you may check [overflow](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/loc13696.html).

```
unset overflow
```

leads to the old behaviour as in v5.2. Otherwise the options are

```
set overflow  {float | NaN | undefined}
```